# Is there a way to prevent Lastpass from logging me in to a website while in private browsing mode?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, password-management

Is there a way to prevent Lastpass from logging me in to a website while in private browsing mode?  Ideally I would like to keep autologin turned on for regular browsing mode, but turn it off for all sites by default in private browsing mode.

Windows 7, Firefox

Comment: Use a different profile that doesn't have the LastPass extension installed or logout out of the extension or disable it then enable it when you are done with private browsing.

Comment: I was hoping for a less extreme option. :(

Comment: You do understand that private browsing mode will use the same profile, which means it isn't exactly "private", it just doesn't keep cookies once the session closes.  Since the LastPass extension is handle outside of the Firefox session, you can either logout of your account, or use another Firefox profile entirely.